# Why doesn't <router-view /> want to be displayed inside <component>?

Tags: vue.js

I switched after vue 2 to vue 3 and I can't understand why  doesn't display anything inside  and how can I make it work

That's how it works

```
<template>
  <component :is="layout"></component>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

That's not how it works

```
<template>
  <component :is="layout">
    <router-view />
  </component>
</template>
```

Comment: If you place `<div>Test</div>` instead of `<router view/>`, does it render? My wild guess is that it doesn't. Probably because the component doesn't have a default slot.

Comment: @tao, This not working

Comment: You have to do better than that. What does *"This"* mean in *"This not working"*? The `<div />` test is not working or it's only `<router-view />` that's not working?